# How to delete all files or Sub-folders (both) in a folder except 2 folders with shell script

Tags: shell, command-line, sh

I would like to know how to deleted all the contents of a folder (it contains other folders and some files) except for 2 folders and its contents

The below command keeps the folder ***conf*** and removes all the other folders

> find . ! -name 'conf' -type d -exec rm -rf {} +

I have tried to pipe it like below

> find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'conf' |find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'foldername2'

but didnt work.

is it possible to do with a single command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified which shell you're using, but if you're using bash then extended globs can help:

```
printf '%s\n' !(@(conf|foldername2)/)
```

If you're happy with the list of files and directories produced by that, then pass the same glob to `rm -rf`:

```
rm -rf !(@(conf|foldername2)/)
```

Inside a script, you may need to enable extglob using `shopt -s extglob`. Later, you can change `-s` to `-u` to unset the option.

---

If you're using a different shell, then you can add some more options to your `find` command:

```
find  -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'conf' -a ! -name 'foldername2' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Try it without the `-exec` part first to print the matches rather than deleting everything.

Comment: Thanks the above answer helped

Answer (score 0):

It may my little program utility can help you. I hope so.

First of all you should find the path of your files `.sh`
then you should find the **main** folder that contains those files `.sh`
then remove anything except those folders

I wrote [drr](https://github.com/k-five/drr) for such a purpose that it can do such a task so easy

drr, stands for: remove or rename files based on regular expression in D language. So you must compile it before using.

See the screenshot:

[image: how to use drr]

> Please be careful since this is not an appropriate tool for beginner.